# Property of normally embedded subgroups

Tags: group-theory

**Definition**: A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be normally embedded in $G$ if each Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of some normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.

**Definition**: A subgroup of $H$ of $G$ is pronormal if for each $g\in G$, the subgroups $H$ and $H^g$ are conjugate in $\langle H, H^g \rangle$.

**Proposition**: If $G$ is a finite solvable group with $H$ normally embedded in $G$, then $H$ is pronormal in $G$.

The following is a exercise in *Finite Soluble Groups* by Doerk and Hawkes (Exercise 1.7.3)

> Let $G$ be a finite group with normally embedded subgroup $H$. Then $G = KN_G(H \cap K)$ for all normal subgroups $K$ of $G$.

The above problem makes no mention of solvability of $G$. However I am not able to show the desired equality unless I assume is solvable.

Let $K \unlhd G$. Then it is easy to show that $H \cap K$ is normally  embedded in $G$. If I assume $G$ is solvable, then $H\cap K$ is pronormal in $G$. So for $g \in G$, there is $x\in \langle H\cap K, H^g \cap K\rangle \leq K$ such that $(H\cap K)^x = (H \cap K)^g$. This implies that $x^{-1}g \in N_G(H \cap K)$, and so $g\in xN_G(H \cap K) \subseteq KN_G(H \cap K)$. Thus $G = KN_G(H\cap K)$.

I'm not sure if this can be proven without the solvablity of $G$